# Sharing a copy register between vim on different machines?

Tags: neovim, os-clipboard, tmux

The image below shows two terminals. Both are running vim instances on remote machines (ssh and a serial connection through an UART cable).

Vim's on those machines don't have a way to access the system clipboard since they are running on physically different machines.

The only way I know to copy content between them is by using the mouse (as shown in the video).

I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this without needing to leave the keyboard. I know the window switching can be solved with introducing `tmux`, but how to solve the problem of a shared copy register?

Some kind of integration with `xterm`?

[image]

Comment: If you are going to use tmux to switch between the two sessions why not use its copy buffer? Also you might want to check [`:h clientserver`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/remote.txt.html#clientserver)

Comment: If the remote machine's vim supports it you can use `ssh -Y` and register `"+`

Comment: If you're using mouse to copy anyway, you should be able to do exact same thing with tmux. I don't have any idea of native vim solution though.

Comment: Did you see `:help clipboard-tool`?